# 2000 Chrysler Town & Country brakes are jamming. I have replaced calipers, rotors and pads

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, chrysler, van

I have a 2000 Chrysler Town & Country van.

I have replaced both front calipers, rotors, and pads.  It is binding though.

1. What are the causes of binding?
2. Is there something that may have happened during the replacement of the pads and rotors that could cause this?

Comment: With the calipers removed from the bracket does it bind? Can you easily compress the caliper piston? If you can't easily compress the piston, what happens when you crack the bleeder? Is it easier to compress the piston? If it isn't, loosen the hose fitting at the metal line. Is it easier to compress the piston? If not try loosening the fitting at the ABS box. If that doesn't work try loosening the fitting at the master cylinder. It sounds like the master cylinder is shot. Obviously test first.

Answer (score 1):

Calipers that tighten easily but don't back off are a result of failing rubber lines. They swell on the inside and block off the brake fluid when it tries to return to the master cylinder. Replace the rubber hoses.